# how add jade in iframe?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have this code in a file `.jade` :

```
iframe(src="file2.jade" width='100%' height='4000' frameborder=0 scrolling='no')
```

the `file2` file is in the same folder as this file, but does not insert the file, what can I do?.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding .jade file to an iframe does not make sense. Iframes are processed by a browser, and browser expects html, not jade.

So the answer depends on what are you trying to do, maybe `include` directive will help.

Comment: but what I do if I need to export the url after having that iframe?

Comment: well you can compile that file2.jade into a file2.html first and then place it somewhere... I didn't understand this question well enough

Comment: 'file2.jade' have a file that I then send to a client, but also want to embed a file 'file.jade'.

Comment: If you really really wanted an iframe, you could add a route which renders the jade template, and then update your iframe src to point to the route

Answer (score 0):

Add one more empty line above `iframe` tag code with the same space (or tab), `.` character is display for a space or tab I mention above.

```
article
..p Some text here (2 space after article block)
..            <--- An empty line with 2 space tab before iframe tag
..iframe(width='560', height='315', src='//www.youtube.com/embed/KpuDq9HyLeg', frameborder='0')
```

It's means have 1 more line above `iframe` tag with the same space (tab) and **inside parent tag of `iframe`**.

It's work for me. Hope this help!